# asp.net SqlDataSource select statement with IN (...) clause

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sqldatasource

I need to pass a server-side parameter to my SqlDataSource SELECT IN-clause as follows (notice the parameter @InClause and it's location in the SQL-select that is defined in the aspx (for the SqlDataSource):

```
SELECT UID_REPORT, TXT_RPT_TEXT, TXT_RPT_NAME, TXT_RPT_ASPX_PAGE, TXT_RPT_TYPE 
FROM REPORTS WHERE (UID_REPORT IN (@InClause)) 
ORDER BY INT_SORT_ORDER
```

But this does not pass validation in the Test-Query operation.
The '@InClause' parameter gets it's value from a HiddenField control.
I want to set this value based on some conditions.  for example If DIVISION=5 then @InClause would ="45,46" Else ="14,15".
Any suggestions on how to pass the IN ( ... ) values by the hiddenfield.Value (which is a string, of course).
Thanks.

Comment: This question again?   http://vyaskn.tripod.com/passing_arrays_to_stored_procedures.htm

Comment: I was searching for similar questions/answers within Stack-Overflow, not asking the internet.  I marked @VR46 as the answer, although your link buries the solution within the six different methods under the context of stored procedures. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `split string` function to do this

```
SELECT uid_report, 
       txt_rpt_text, 
       txt_rpt_name, 
       txt_rpt_aspx_page, 
       txt_rpt_type 
FROM   reports 
WHERE  uid_report IN (SELECT split_value 
                      FROM   Udf_splitstring(@InClause, ',')) 
ORDER  BY int_sort_order
```

Check the below links to create a split string function

1. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings
2. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

or of-course you can use `dynamic sql`

Comment: Is your posted code working in ASPX page select command or inside a SQL-Server script window?  The select-code I posted resides within a SqlDataControl in aspx code.

Comment: i dont have anything to validate

Comment: I used your posted SQL code within the SqlDataSource select-command within the aspx code and it worked perfectly.  I have a splitString function in my dbo but I did not know I could embed it within the aspx page.  I use it many times within stored procedures. Thanks.